# Errores al compilar proyecto importado de GitHub. Android - Eclipse (Funciona en modo Debug)

Tags: java

Estoy intentando compilar un proyecto el cual en principio esta debugueado y es funcional pero al compilarlo obtengo una serie de errores que describo a continuación:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method getListCellRendererComponent(JList, Object, int, boolean, boolean) of type ContactPanel.ImageListCellRenderer must override a superclass method  ContactPanel.java   /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 451    Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    VideoPanel.java /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 185    Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type VideoHandler must override a superclass method   VideoHandler.java   /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type VideoHandler must override a superclass method  VideoHandler.java   /AndroratServer/src/handler line 27 Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    ContactPanel.java   /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 262    Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    ContactPanel.java   /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 120    Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    ContactPanel.java   /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 111    Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    ContactPanel.java   /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 102    Java Problem
The method getRowCount() of type UserModel must override a superclass method    UserModel.java  /AndroratServer/src/gui line 78 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type PictureHandler must override a superclass method PictureHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type PictureHandler must override a superclass method    PictureHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 27 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type CallMonitorHandler must override a superclass method    CallMonitorHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 27 Java Problem
The method getColumnCount() of type UserModel must override a superclass method UserModel.java  /AndroratServer/src/gui line 83 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type SMSMonitorHandler must override a superclass method  SMSMonitorHandler.java  /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method getValueAt(int, int) of type UserModel must override a superclass method UserModel.java  /AndroratServer/src/gui line 116    Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type SMSMonitorHandler must override a superclass method SMSMonitorHandler.java  /AndroratServer/src/handler line 31 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type ClientLogHandler must override a superclass method  ClientLogHandler.java   /AndroratServer/src/handler line 27 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type ClientLogHandler must override a superclass method   ClientLogHandler.java   /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method windowClosing(WindowEvent) of type UserGUI must override a superclass method UserGUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 93 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type CommandHandler must override a superclass method CommandHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 106    Java Problem
The method windowIconified(WindowEvent) of type UserGUI must override a superclass method   UserGUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 675    Java Problem
The method windowDeiconified(WindowEvent) of type UserGUI must override a superclass method UserGUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 679    Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type CommandHandler must override a superclass method    CommandHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 28 Java Problem
The method windowOpened(WindowEvent) of type UserGUI must override a superclass method  UserGUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 667    Java Problem
The method windowClosed(WindowEvent) of type UserGUI must override a superclass method  UserGUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 671    Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type CallMonitorHandler must override a superclass method CallMonitorHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method windowActivated(WindowEvent) of type UserGUI must override a superclass method   UserGUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 683    Java Problem
The method windowDeactivated(WindowEvent) of type UserGUI must override a superclass method UserGUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 687    Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type PreferenceHandler must override a superclass method PreferenceHandler.java  /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type PreferenceHandler must override a superclass method  PreferenceHandler.java  /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 622    Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 599    Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 590    Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type FileHandler must override a superclass method    FileHandler.java    /AndroratServer/src/handler line 48 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type FileHandler must override a superclass method   FileHandler.java    /AndroratServer/src/handler line 89 Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 680    Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 666    Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type SoundHandler must override a superclass method   SoundHandler.java   /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 657    Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type ContactsHandler must override a superclass method   ContactsHandler.java    /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 648    Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type ContactsHandler must override a superclass method    ContactsHandler.java    /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method    GUI.java    /AndroratServer/src/gui line 632    Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type SoundHandler must override a superclass method  SoundHandler.java   /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type FileTreeHandler must override a superclass method    FileTreeHandler.java    /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type SMSHandler must override a superclass method SMSHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type FileTreeHandler must override a superclass method   FileTreeHandler.java    /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type CallLogHandler must override a superclass method CallLogHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type CallLogHandler must override a superclass method    CallLogHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type SMSHandler must override a superclass method    SMSHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type GPSHandler must override a superclass method    GPSHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 23 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type GPSHandler must override a superclass method GPSHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 35 Java Problem
The type sun.management.OperatingSystemImpl is not visible  VideoPanel.java /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 36 Java Problem
The method handlePacket(Packet, String, Server) of type AdvInfoHandler must override a superclass method    AdvInfoHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 26 Java Problem
The method receive(Packet, String) of type AdvInfoHandler must override a superclass method AdvInfoHandler.java /AndroratServer/src/handler line 21 Java Problem
```

Quería hacer para la universidad una pequeña aplicación remota y por eso me puse a ver esta en concreto de este proyecto:
[Enlace al proyecto](https://github.com/wszf/androrat)

Aqui muestro una captura de los errores que me muestra, la aplicación cliente se compila bien pero la aplicación servidor cuando lo compilo desde su función principal me devuelve los errores citados. Aqui os pongo una captura de los errores que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar o alguien lo ha intentado explicarme como hacerlo, ya que pienso que el proyecto no tiene errores en sí, sino que habre hecho alguna falta o me falto por incluir algo. También no entiendo muy bien estos errores y estoy un poco perdido en java.
Lo hacía simplemente con fines educativos y para aprender, en mi caso quería ver como funcionaba una pequeña aplicación remota desde el código, si alguien pudiera darme mas información o explicarme como puedo resolver estos errores para compilar el proyecto y entender mejor como funciona por favor ya que no se como pedir ayuda en esto.

Comment: Hola:
Están protestando los '@Override' de las interfaces. Sólo se puede poner '@Override' de una interface en java 1.6 o superior.
¿Estás usando una versión de java anterior?

Comment: Lo pondré como respuesta para que pueda valorar. Al añadir la versión de java de nuevo funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto al añadirla a mi proyecto me aparece con una versión de java superior, la versión jr 1.8.0, entonces me muestra los siguientes errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que hago es cambiar a java SE 1.7(se supone que con la 1.8 debería funcionar pero al hacer el cambio a la 1.7 me funciona):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el proyecto que cite se ejecuta correctamente.